# how to get listview id in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

How can i get the id of an item (_id of almag table)? the item comes from sqlite (retrieve from sqlite) and it is showed in listview. I want to get the id and i want to use the id later (to be saved in sqlite into score table as userId).

Here is code to create table

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE almag (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nama TEXT, jekel TEXT);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE score (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, score INTEGER, userId INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES almag(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);"); //create table score
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom listview that includes a string, textview or whatever you want. You could follow this tutorial:

http://www.anddev.org/android_filebrowser__v20-t101.html

to make a list view and just remove the icons if you don't want them.

//André

Comment: i can create the listview, but i want to get the id then i can use it later on.